# cocos2d CCMenuItemImage in child layer target:self SIGABRT

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a child layer that I'm adding to the scene which contains a menu, it is initialized like so:

```
- (id) init
{
if((self=[super init]))
{
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCMenuItemImage* attackButton = [CCMenuItemImage
                                    itemFromNormalImage:@"btnAttack.png" 
                                    selectedImage:@"btnAttack.png"
                                    target: self
                                    selector:@selector(attack)];

    CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:attackButton,  nil];
    menu.position = ccp(winSize.width-80,winSize.height-140);
    [menu alignItemsHorizontally];
    [self addChild:menu];   

}
return self;
}
```

This crashes with a SIGABRT error unless I change the target: to 'nil'. Why is this not working and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should crash if you don't have attack: defined in your class.
Do you really need a parameter to attack?

Easy steps to check if that's your problem:

1) remove the param, change the code to:

```
target: self
selector:@selector(attack)];
```

2) add the attack method, and check the console output:

```
-(void)attack
{
   NSLog(@"test");
}
```

To better understand where is the problem, show the breakpoints in your navigator bar, click the plus button and add exception breakpoint ... so when the app crashes (if still does) you can see the call stack and see what's wrong

Comment: attack is defined and I've removed the : from the selector, yet the problem still persists. It crashes on the CCMenuItemImage declaration

Comment: very weird ... the code looks ok, and the method names are correct

Comment: Strangely, defining attack in the interface fixed it

Comment: wow! that's an interesting bug ... I never do define the menu items' delegates in the interface and it all works ... you can try using blocks too - to avoid such bugs like this one

Answer (score 0):

This same this is happen with me when i create ccmenuitemimage. so you need to check your metdhod that you calling in as a selector.